# Fbq (Facebook pixel) is undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, facebook-pixel, bugsnag

fbq seems to be undefined in Edge and IE (11 in this case). The errors are being reported in Bugsnag if anyone is wondering where I can see them.

Are there any particular configurations i can get for this to work in these browsers? I've checked it out on Browserstack and in a VM for each and can't seem to replicate the issue...